# Is there a method to get row number with a method of Vaadin ClickListener's event?

Tags: row, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I have a Grid with four columns. The last one contains an image, which I make clickable by adding a ClickListener to its ImageRenderer. My goal is to access the row (or all of its elements) to delete the row.

```
  Grid<Row> grid = new Grid<>();
 
    ...
        
        grid.addColumn(row -> row.getValue("NAME")).setCaption("NAME");
        
        grid.addColumn(row -> row.getValue("PHONE")).setCaption("PHONE");
        
        grid.addColumn(row -> row.getValue("EMAIL")).setCaption("EMAIL");
        
        ImageRenderer ir = new ImageRenderer();
            ir.addClickListener(
                    event -> {
                        System.out.println(event.getItem());
                        
                    }); 
        grid.addColumn(row -> row.getValue("icon_delete"), ir).setCaption("");
```

My question is one concerning the ImageRenderer’s ClickListener: event has a method called getItem() - yet I have not found a way to get the number of the row containing the clicked item. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need the row number? You have the item in your renderer, delete it from the data provider and refresh it.

```java
data.remove(event.getItem());
data.refreshAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

For any people who come to this question with some other need for the row number:

Grid doesn't know the row numbers, you need to ask the data provider or whatever you use for providing data for the data provider. That something might be a database or a simple ArrayList that you used to generate some dummy data. Data provider implementations don't usually have a direct method for querying the row numbers either, but if the data provider isn't lazy, you could get the entire item list, put it into an ArrayList, and ask the ArraList for the `indexOf`. With lazy data you are probably better off querying the original source.

The same 'it depends on your implementation' goes for whether there is an easy way to access any potential filters or comparators or TreeGrid items' expand/collapse status that might affect the displayed order. You will at the very least need to cast the data provider into its actual implementation class because the generic DataProvider interface doesn't provide those methods.

For the most part row numbers are not relevant information for Grid's needs.