# how can I get the selected row in a vaadin flow grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid, vaadin14

How can I get the selected row index in a grid?
Something like

```
int selectedRowIndex = grid.getSelectedRowIndex();
```

I already have the following if it can help

```
Set<Record> selectedRow = (Set<Record>)((SelectionModel) grid.getSelectionModel()).getSelectedItems();
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you please be more specific what you are after and how that what you have tried has failed? My _guess_ is, that you want to know the absolute index of the selected items intead of the items themself? In that case: the grid is basically an "infinite scrolling list" and it does not track position other than mapping between server and client. You could make the index part of your view model.

Comment: For most purposes knowing the item is more important than knowing the exact index of it. If you do need the index for some reason, you need to get it from your data source, not Grid. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68362320/is-there-a-method-to-get-row-number-with-a-method-of-vaadin-clicklisteners-even/68376052#68376052